# Не всегда срабатывает onLoad

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток! почему этот код:

```
        $(window).on('load',function(){
            $('#core_extensions').load('index.php?                       task=getPage&ext=core_extensions&params='+url.pop());
        });
```

срабатывает через раз? в опере вообще раз через 10

Comment: Попробуйте ставить на $(document).ready() т.к. событие onLoad вызывается сразу после загрузки страницы, не дожидаясь завершения построения DOM

Comment: событие load вызывается в момент полной готовности страницы - когда загружены абсолютно все элементы. события ready вызывается когда готово дерево DOM, что происходит раньше

Comment: [onDOMContentLoaded](http://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded)

Comment: мне не нужно событие, которое наступает раньше, чем onload - мне нужно наоборот - дождаться, когда загрузится страница и выполнятся все ajax запросы

Comment: Событие onLaod может вообще не наступить и подписываться на него глупо. Зачем вам это?

Comment: мне нужно подгрузить через ajax элемент, когда страница полностью готова - т.е. даже ajax запросы завершены.

Comment: @woland

> и выполнятся все ajax запросы

не думаю что `$(window).on('load');` гарантирует это. что за переменная url ? может она из ajax получается ? повесьте кастомное событие, делайте триггер его после вызова ajax. либо воспользуйтесь 

[`jQuery.holdReady()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.holdReady/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/g3D7f/1/  — если что, я этого не писал.

```
(function (){
    var _ready = $.Deferred(), _ajax = $.Deferred();

    $(function (){
        if( !$.active ){
             _ajax.resolve();
        }
        _ready.resolve();
    });
    $(document).one('ajaxStop', _ajax.resolve);

    $.when(_ready, _ajax).always(function (){
        alert('All ready, perhaps.');
    });
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 /* code */
});
```

Comment: вы издеваетесь? почитайте мои комментарии выше